# average of reciprocal of sum of random variables

Tags: random-variables, exponential-distribution

I have a slightly more complex problem, but I believe the technical nature is captured in the following:

For the $s$-indexed sequence, $X_s$, of iid positive-valued random variables with finite density at $0$, the average of random variable $Y$, with

$Y=\sum_{s=1}^{N}\frac{1}{X_s} , $

diverges because vanishing samples of $X_s$ dominate the sum, leading it to diverge, and thus the reciprocal vanishes.

The average of the reciprocal of $Y$, $Z=1/Y$ is not affected by this and so is still finite. I would like to know how to calculate the average of $Z$ for a given distribution of $X_s$, say exponential. Take $N$ large if it helps.

It is useful to know how to compute [inverse distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_distribution) and [quotient distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution).

I am not so familiar with random variable algebra and found the ill-defined distribution of the intermediate $Y$ variable an impediment to the application of the standard step-wise transformation of random variables.

Thank you in advance for even partial progress towards a solution.

EDIT: mathematica stalls trying to do the expectation for $N=3$. The answer it gives for $N=2$ is $\frac{1}{3\lambda}$, where $\lambda$ is the parameter of the exponential distribution of $X_s$.

Comment: The random variable $Z$ is not well defined since $P(N=0)\ne0$.

Comment: thanks! Fixed that with $k>0$.

Comment: I simplified the problem and highlighted my difficulty. Thanks!